# Ansible's with_together Directive Only Allows 2 Lists

Tags: ansible

It looks like `with_together` only allows two lists, as seen below:

```
- name: combine items
  set_fact:
    commandList: "{{ commandList }} + [ '{{ item[0].path }} {{ item[1].path }} {{ item[3].path }}' ]"
  with_together:
    - "{{ findXmls['files'] }}"
    - "{{ findEars['files'] }}"
    - "{{others['files'] }}"
```

This **fails when adding the 3rd list** called `others`. It will fail even when the 3rd list is a duplicate of one of the others, so it isn't a structural/formatting issue.

**Is this standard behavior?**

If so, how would I go about doing something like a `with_together` that would allow me to use 3 lists together?

It has to work like `with_together` because it needs to be a 1:1 mapping from each nth element to the other lists' nth elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works fine for N lists. You should access items with zero-based indexes:

```
'{{ item[0].path }} {{ item[1].path }} {{ item[2].path }}'
```

This is example for 3 lists.

You have a typo while trying to access third item – it should be `item[2]`, not `item[3]`.

Comment: Oh man... I can't believe I put 3 instead of 2. Thanks for pointing that out; I never would've noticed on my own